# Video chat with 5 people and Wowza Server

Tags: android, wowza, videochat

I´m developing a video chat app for Android with wowza server, working fine at this moment.
But, I´m using 5 VideoViews in the same activity to play incoming stream.

Too much delay... :(

Perhaps, if I use MediaPlayer and SurfaceView, I can stop having delay incoming stream?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Finally, I used MediaPlayer with SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder, but same delay. Any idea? Maybe, Wowza server not working for videochat?

Comment: For every stream, there is always buffering happening in background. And when you open 5 VideoViews means 5 different video buffering is happenig that will slow down your phone to extreme extent and your phone may event restart if low RAM. You can stream 5 videos on your phone, but pescribed not to do that.